# How to put a vertical scroll bar on a dijit menu

Tags: javascript, html, widget, dojo

I would like to create a `dijit` menu that has a `vertical` scroll bar.

I've tried doing this:

```
pMenu = new dijit.Menu({
           templateString: '<div style="height: 75px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x:hidden">' + dojo.cache("dijit", "templates/Menu.html") + '</div>'
        });
```

When I do that, the vertical scroll bar appears but the width is to small (it didn't expand to account for the scroll bars width).

Is there a better way to do this?  I essentially want a `maxHeight` attribute on dijit.menu

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea to show you how you could detect element scrollbar presence:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Detect Scrollbars Presence</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function verticalScrollBarExists(id)
            {
                var element = document.getElementById(id);
                oldScrollTop = element.scrollTop;
                element.scrollTop = 1;
                if (element.scrollTop > 0)
                {
                    element.scrollTop = oldScrollTop;
                    document.getElementById('scrollStatus').innerHTML = 'scroll bar visible';

                    // increase element width
                    element.style.width = '310px';
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById('scrollStatus').innerHTML = 'scroll bar not visible';

                    // restore element width
                    element.style.width = '300px';
                }
            }

            function add()
            {
                var element = document.getElementById('testElement');
                element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + ' Stuff';
            }

            function remove()
            {
                var element = document.getElementById('testElement');
                element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.substring(0, element.innerHTML.length - 6);
            }

            window.onload = function()
            {
                setInterval('verticalScrollBarExists("testElement")', 500);
            };
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #testElement
            {
                width: 300px;
                height: 40px;
                background-color: blue;
                color: white;
                overflow: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testElement">Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff Stuff</div>
        <div id="scrollStatus">Uninitialised</div>
        <input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Add" />
        <input type="button" onclick="remove()" value="Remove" />
    </body>
</html>
```